# Bootstrap a proportion (of factor levels) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long format data frame where rows represent the responses (one of four categories) of different people. An example dataset is provided here:

```
df <- data.frame(person=c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)),resp=c(sample(4,100,replace=TRUE),sample(4,100,replace=TRUE)))
df$resp <- factor(df$resp)
summary(df)
person  resp  
A:100   1:52  
B:100   2:55  
        3:54  
        4:39
```

I want to present a chart where the x-axis plots the response category, the y-axis shows the proportion of responses in a category, and where error bars are calculated via bootstrapping (sampling with replacement).

I can calculate the proportion (in an extremely kludgy way; I'm sure this could be improved but this is not my main concern):

```
pFrame <- ddply(df,.(person,resp),summarise,trials = length(resp))
# can't figure out how to calculate the proportion with plyr.
pFrame$prop <- NA
people <- unique(df$person)
responses <- unique(df$resp)
for (i in 1 : length(people)){
  nTrials <- nrow(subset(df,person==people[i]))
  for (j in 1 : 4){
    pFrame$prop[pFrame$person==people[i] & pFrame$resp==responses[j]] <- pFrame$trials[pFrame$person==people[i] & pFrame$resp==responses[j]] /  nTrials 
  }
}
```

and plot it:

```
ggplot(pFrame,aes(x=resp,y=prop,colour=person)) + geom_point()
```

but I would really like to use something like `stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot")` to show the variability on the proportions (i.e. acting on the original data frame `df`, and bootstrapping over the rows). I've tried a few attempts at creating custom functions but this doesn't seem trivial because the factor levels need to be transformed for the bootstrap first.

Comment: FYI, here is a short version for the proportion: ggplot(df, aes(x = resp, color = person)) + geom_point(stat = "bin")

Comment: Thanks @cafe876, but as I point out below, this returns the number of rows rather than the proportion of responses. Since my data actually has unequal numbers of rows between people, I would like the proportions rather than the count. This requires dividing each bin by the total number across bins for each person... which is why I ended up writing the kludgy loops above (couldn't figure out how to do this with the plyr package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get ggplot's "mean_cl_boot" to work. Here is an alternative solution though:

```
library(boot)

summary_for_plot <- melt(prop.table(table(df), 1))
names(summary_for_plot) <- c("person", "resp", "V1")

# function for boot()
summary_function <- function(df, d){
  melt(prop.table(table(df[d,]), 1))[, 3]
}

bootres <- boot(df, statistic = summary_function, R=100)
# get the standard deviation, used for the confidence intervals
summary_for_plot$sd <- sd(bootres$t)

ggplot(summary_for_plot, aes(x= resp, y = V1, color = person)) + geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = V1-sd, ymax = V1+sd), width = 0.2)
```

Comment: That does the job, thanks cafe876. It's a shame that this is not easily engineered through ggplot.

Comment: Ok, so these solutions work for returning (and bootstrapping over) the number of rows, which equates to 100*proportion here because of my example dataset. What I'm really after is the **proportion** and the uncertainty associated with this, because in my actual data, the different people have different numbers of rows. Any idea how to get plyr to divide by the sum of a subcategory?

Comment: @waldog I updated the code to get the proportions and don't use plyr anymore (it has no built-in option to compute proportions). It is a bit less elegant but much faster!